# Get high quality profile picture from GoogleSignInAccount

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

In my Android application in order to authenticate through the **google account**, I follow this official tutorial https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people#retrieve_profile_information_for_a_signed-in_user and it works.

As stated there, to retrieve the profile picture I use "**getPhotoUrl()**" method of "GoogleSignInAccount" class. Example:

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
String personId = acct.getId();
Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
```

The **problem** is that the image that I get through this URL is very poor quality (small size).

[Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsh4D.png)

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: may I know what is url you are getting.. value of this object `personPhoto`

Comment: Official documentation says : "Returns the photo url of the signed in user if the user has a profile picture..."

Comment: yes.. does that url ends with `sz=50`?.... post that image url

Comment: At the end there is something like "s96-c/photo.jpg". Changing it for example in "s500-c/photo.jpg" I can get an image of 500x500 size. I think it is not the proper way to do but I can not find another solution.

Comment: check my updated answer.. with official document link

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your photo url has `sz=50` key (image size 50 or something). Then replace size to the highest. like `sz=240`

I am not sure your photo url has `sz` key because I used `Person` API which has `sz` key  for `getUrl()` to get user details which is now deprecated.

**UPDATED:** [Person.Image](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.Image#public-methods) -
**Official doc** which says how to get different dimens of profile avatar

> The URL of the person's profile photo. To resize the image and crop it to a square, append the query string ?sz=x, where x is the dimension in pixels of each side

However as @stackpic91 said new API `GoogleSignInAccount.getPhotoUrl()` has **`S96-c`** change its value to the highest to get large image **`S240-c`**

Comment: There is not a way to select a specific dimension in the method getPhotoUrl() but I noticed that at the end of the URL there is something like "S96-c / photo.jpg". Changing it for example in "s500-c" I can get an image of 500x500 size. I think it is not the proper way to do but I can not find another solution.

Comment: actually that is the only way and which is proper... google checks what image size you need and returns the same dimes you set in the url..

Comment: These values don't work for me. Looks like only multiples of `96` work. For example: `s96-c`, `s192-c`, `s384-c`.

Comment: @stackpic91 please post the answer as your comment says with appropriate code it must be the accepted answers as there are many threads on SO for the same. Thank you for your suggestion, I tried with 1024 and it is successful.

Answer (score 15):

When loading the image with whatever loader you choose (Glide/Picasso), just do this to the url string:

```
avatarUrl.replace("s96-c", "s192-c", true)
```

or

```
avatarUrl.replace("s96-c", "s384-c", true)
```

for even better quality

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. If change the query params in the URL, you will good quality image
for example:
`https://lh3.googleusercontent.co/a/ALm5wu1o3Bl7PnfBQnEPcJuTj2v9FDcqaiCouOVPaO-3=s96-sn-c`

from the last of URL just remove `=s96-sn-c` you will get good resolution image

so the params are :

- sn    size    Sets the longer of height or width to n pixels, i.e. s1000
- wn    width   Sets width of image to n pixels
- hn    height  Sets height of image to n pixels
- c     square crop     Sets height and width of crop to the same value

check [doc](https://developers.google.com/people/image-sizing) for more