# Google Signin getImageUrl() Image size

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am adding google signin to my website and I can not find any documentation that explains how to specify the size of the image returned by the getImageUrl() from the getBasicProfile() code. Here is the code i am using:

```
function startApp() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'apps.googleusercontent.com',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        });
        attachSignin(document.getElementById('gLogin'));
    });
};

startApp();

function attachSignin(element) {
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {}, function(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/example.com',
            data: {
                ID: profile.getId(),
                firstName: profile.getGivenName(),
                lastName: profile.getFamilyName(),
                profileImage: profile.getImageUrl(),
                emailAddress: profile.getEmail(),
                tokenID: googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token,
                formID: 'gLogin'
            },
            success:function(data) {
                if (data == 'success') {
                    window.location.reload(false);
                }else{
                    alert(data);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('There was an error in our system! Please try again later.');
            }

        }) // End of Ajax Code

    }, function(error) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
    });
}
```

Essentially this code works perfectly for my situation but the image returned by profile.getImageUrl() returns a 50px image. How do I specify what size I need returned? Is there a way?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving profile image from Google+ API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020985/retrieving-profile-image-from-google-api)

Comment: Its not a duplicate as I have seen that post. I am trying to get the size from the getBasicProfile() function not sending a get request for only the image.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your question where you mention reading that post. `getImageUrl` does not take any parameters, so I expect it's not possible.

Comment: I am not sure why I would mention reading that post when it is a completely different situation than my post?

Answer (score 0):

In the url that Google gives you, replace 's96-c' with 'sX-c' where X is the image size you want. I'm kinda amazed at how hard this was for me to find. Must have spent an hour or two looking around for the answer. Ended up finding it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55630187/2576959